# Trigger in Google Form submit does not work properly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a script that is running when a form is submitted. The script does not work when I use a function with the `e` parameter such as the code below.  I get a message returned: `ReferenceError: 'e' is not defined.` Any idea why?

```js
function submitFormFunc(e) {
  var items = e.response.getResponses();
  var responses={};
  for(var i = 0; i< items.length; i++) {
   responses[items[i].getItem().getTitle()]=items[i].getResponse();
  }

  var responseTable = [];
  var responseIndex = ["Timestamp","ID","question 1","question 2"];
  responseTable.push(e.response.getTimestamp().toString());
  responseTable.push(e.response.getId());
  responseTable.push(responses["question 1"]);
  responseTable.push(responses["question 2"]);
  responseTable.push(FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponse(e.response.getId()).getEditResponseUrl());
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("your spreadsheetId").appendRow(responseTable);
}
```

Comment: How does `submitFormFunc` get called? Are you binding it to the submit event handler for the form? If so, how? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, I have defined a trigger for this script on spreadsheet form submit (script editor=> tools=> triggers for this project) . A simple script works fine, but the trigger is not working for the script above.

Comment: Message has changed (message is in Dutch, translated) submitFormFunc TypeError: Kan methode getResponses van undefined niet aanroepen. (regel 2, bestand 'Code'). Translate: "submitFormFunc TypeError: Cannot call method getResponses from undefined. (line 2, file 'Code')"

Comment: Tried to use another method, which works correctly:
var question = e.values[2].
Apparently the script does not accept the line

Comment: Tried to use another method, which works correctly:
var question = e.values[2].
Apparently the script does not recognize the line
var items = e.response.getResponses();

Comment: To anyone else led astray by the `[javascript]` tag - this question is specific to the Google Apps Script environment, and its Forms service - the normal concerns about HTML form submit events mentioned by Anthony are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving that error because the event object, `e`, isn't defined when you've called `submitFormFunc(e)`. This is typical when you are debugging, and have invoked a parameterized function from the editor/debugger.

For your testing, simulate the event using the technique from [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas/16089067#16089067)

Comment: The nice thing about good answers is that you can reuse them indefinitely :-) , in french we say "cent fois sur le métier remettez votre ouvrage"..., which means in short that repetition should not be discouraging.